# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet" - when using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I run auto-py-to-exe and got this error after clicking on the .exe file.
Any experts here know the problem? (I quite new to Python so hope can explain more in details)

```
  File "requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to install library 'chardet'? You should open your virtual environment in a terminal.

```
<virtual_environment_name>/bin/activate.
```

After that you should run

```
pip install chardet.
```

Comment: I followed your instruction and install: pip install chardet and now it work wonder! Thank you!